# Apache Beam - ParquetIO + SparkRunner (reading issue)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-beam, parquet

I am currently running an Apache Beam application using *sparkRunner* in our on-premise Cloudera Hadoop Cluster, I am using **Apache Beam 2.16** and **Apache Spark 2.4**.
I have 2 versions of the same pipeline, one reading from AVRO data and another reading from Parquet (Code below)

```
PCollection<GenericRecord> records = pipeline
  .apply("Reading",ParquetIO.read(SCHEMA)
  .from("/foo/bar"));

records.apply("Writing",AvroIO.writeGenericRecords(SCHEMA)
  .to(options.getOutputPath())
  .withSuffix(".avro"));
```

We have seen an unexpected behavior between the execution reading avro and parquet. Reading AVRO, the following stages are present in the DAG (screenshot 1)
[image]

we are reading 2gb size of data, 15 number of files (compressed with Snappy)
however running the same pipeline (but reading parquet) we have seen that the stages are different and there is an additiona repartition step running in a single task (screenshot 2)
[image]

The execution of the pipeline fail in the case of Parquet data because that "work overload" (single task), I tried add some extra spark flags but it is still failing.
An example of one execution with that extra flags is:

```
spark2-submit --master yarn --class my.class.MainClass \
--driver-memory 8G \
--executor-cores 5 \
--driver-cores 5 \
--conf spark.driver.memory=10G \
--conf spark.executor.memory=10G \
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=2000 \
--conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=2000 \
--conf spark.yarn.am.memoryOverhead=2000 \
--conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializer \
--conf spark.network.timeout=1200 \
--conf spark.speculation=true \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=20 \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=10 \
--conf spark.shuffle.spill=true \
--conf spark.shuffle.spill.compress=true \
--conf spark.io.compression.codec=snappy \
--conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=10000000 \
--conf spark.network.timeout=10000000 \
--conf spark.default.parallelism=100 \
/parent/path/program.jar \
--inputPath="/this/is/the/input/path" \
--outputPath="/this/is/the/output/path" \
--runner=SparkRunner
```

If someone can help me with some workaround to fix that "work overload" of reading parquet data will be very helpful :)